# Can't import TilesConfigurer even though its dependency is right

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

i'm following a course about Spring Framework. In this course, my teacher is explaining Tiles and uses TilesConfigurer (this is a 2019 course). My problem is that i cannot import this TilesConfigurer class.

I added all the right dependency, even deprecated ones that required me adding additional repositories. I found that the correct dependency should be this one:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
     <version>6.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

But still, nothing. Any help? Should i use something else?

Comment: You didn't add the right dependencies, the course being from 2019 is using older dependencies, you decided to use newer versions. Tiles support has been removed in Spring 6. If you are following a course, stay with the versions of frameworks used in that tutorial.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!